# How to do arbitary text replacement in gnu assembler

Tags: gcc, assembly, macros

```
a:.int 0
movl $0,a(%rip)
```

Is there a way to do something like `#define b a(%rip)` such that every instance of `b` will be replaced by `a(%rip)`, so that `movl $0,a(%rip)` could be abbreviated as `movl $0,b`? I've tried both `b=a(%rip)` and `.macro b;a(%rip);.endm` but neither worked. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can preprocess your file with the C preprocessor and then indeed use `#define b a(%rip)`. To have the file preprocessed with the C preprocessor, use the file suffix `.S` instead of `.s` and assemble like this:

```
cc -c file.S
```

Note that a definition like this is very unusual and confusing to readers. Instead of trying to change assembler syntax that is confusing to you by the mean of macros, I recommend you to get familiar with the syntax and the reasons why you use a `%rip`-relative addressing mode instead.